# Call function in parent component without using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a an App component that renders a `CustomerForm` component like so:

App.js

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {logged_in: true};

    }

    logout = () => {
      this.setState({logged_in: false}):
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <CustomerForm />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my `CustomerForm` component, I have an `onSubmit` function that is called when the form submits:

CustomerForm.js

```
class CustomerForm extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){
         this.state = { submitting: false }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.setState({submitting: true});
       try{
           //API CALL HERE
       }catch(e){
           //if error == unauthorized, then logout. 
       }

    }
}
```

When I render the `CustomerForm` component from the `App` component, I realize that I could pass a reference to `logout` via a prop, however, my application is much larger than the one I have provided here. Ultimately, I want to be able to call the `logout()` function that is in the `App` component from either like a helper file or any nested component (preferably a helper file). Once this function is called, the state for the `App` component would be updated to reflect that the user is now logged out. I tried to use `createContext` and this allowed me to pass the attributes and functions I needed, however the functions were only available in the JSX like so:

```
<authContext.Consumer>
    {({logout}) => {
      return (
    
        <Form onSubmit={logout}/>
      );
    }}
</authContext.Consumer>
```

However, I need to be able to access `logout` from within the `handleSubmit` function. I know that I can pass the `logout` function as a reference to handleSubmit, but I figure there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Since you seem to be looking for some sort of global state / actions you can call from within your child components, you might want to consider using the useReducer hook or redux

Comment: You can use react context API to handle such cases. Check the example here, how to handle global state 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management

Comment: @Cannon You can check my blog, https://devsmitra.medium.com/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-2968a5cf5c83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Context api` and `HOC`, you can do that. let  me know your thought.

app.js

```
/ Create a new context for the app
export const AppContext = React.createContext('app');

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {logged_in: true};
    }

    logout = () => {
      this.setState({logged_in: false}):
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <AppContext.Provider
                value={{
                    state: this.state,
                    logout: this.logout
                }}
            >
                <CustomerForm />
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Create a HOC for your Context

withAppContext.js

```
import {AppContext} from './app.js'

export function withAppContext(Component) {
    return function WrapperComponent(props) {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {state => <Component {...props} context={state} />}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        );
    };
}
```

CustomerForm.js

```
import { withAppContext } from 'withAppContext.js'

class CustomerForm extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){
         this.state = { submitting: false }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
       this.props.context.logout();
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Child</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>logout</button>
      </>
    );
  }

}

export default withAppContext(CustomerForm);
```

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-hoc-65502223-qqnod)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to use context in both parent component and child component, by using content in the parent component, you will define your parent component's states not internally but in content to use and also by using in child component(s) to change that data.

But, for getting able to do this, you need to change your component to a functional component to get able to use useContent() hook which is just available in functional components.

for more information, check here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext